# Right Way of creating a front end dev build system

Tags: javascript, gulp, build-system

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this, so please bear with me.

I'm quite new to build systems/ front end workflow and have relied heavily on IDE built in systems to do the work for me such as compiling Sass to css.

I recently discovered the world of npm gulp and now need to get a project working  and compiled from a "dev" folder to a "build" folder.

1. What im not understanding is if a install bootstrap via npm it adds
   in to the node_modules folder outside of these two folders. Am I
   doing something wrong here? because I cd into the dev folder but yet
   it installed it in the root folder.
2. how do I change my  tag rev files from my dev to build if I 
   have to get files from the node_modules
3. The same goes for Angular, it is installed in the node_modules folder. how do I go about accessing the code from there to my dev folder and then compiling it to my build.

Answer (score 1):

This works with the way node resolve modules. If you install a module like `gulp`, you will have a structure similar to this:

```
- node_modules/
    - gulp/
        ...
- src/
    index.js
gulpfile.js
```

In order to import `gulp` into your script, you can just use `require('gulp')` (or `import gulp from 'gulp'` if you are using EcmaScript6) and node will find out where to look for this module.

You can do it both from the `gulpfile.js` or from `src/index.js`. Node will try to find the `node_modules` folder in the script folder, or in any parent folder.

Comment: Sorry @Thiago i'm not understand a word you say. I know that i require gulp and all gulp plugins from my gulpfile.js. i do not understand however how to get working with bootstrap and/or if i use angular from my dev build if it lies outside of the dev folder in root folder, and then to compile it to a build folder.

Answer (score 0):

For most front-end build systems, your node_modules folder actually sits at the root of your project folder. Your `dev` folder (i.e. where you put your source code) which is a sub-folder of your project root, will then be able to see npm modules installed into the project root folder.

Note that in many front-end setups I've seen, the convention is to call that `dev` folder `src` instead.

Comment: sorry if i sound stupid, but how do i reverence this from my src file? would it be ../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css. if so do i the use gulp-concat to concat bootstrap with my compiled sass?

Comment: yes, the above would work, but in most cases, you grab npm installed code using `require`  ... eg require('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css').  If you are new to frontend builds, i'd suggest skipping gulp and checking out webpack - it allows you to require css the same way you require js. It has a learning curve, but so does gulp and if you don't know anything, best to learn the better technique from the get-go

Answer (score 0):

I would set it up this way, use the app folder for development purposes, while the dist (as in "distribution") folder is used to contain optimized files for the production site.

Since app is used for development purposes, all your code will be placed in app and will compile in the dist folder when you run something like `gulp build`

```
  |- app/
    |- css/
    |- fonts/
    |- images/ 
    |- index.html
    |- js/ 
    |- scss/
  |- dist/
  |- gulpfile.js
  |- node_modules/
  |- package.json
```